# Java - How to navigate through object array with buttons

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to implement a "Previous" and "Next" button. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to navigate through an object array with the buttons and display on the fields.

To clarify I would like my button to iterate through the object array and display it into the fields according to the pointer with each click.

An example of what I want to do:

Button click

display myProduct at pointer 0

Button click

display myProduct at pointer 1

Button click

display myProduct at pointer 2

So far I've managed to do this:

```
Product[] myProduct = new Product[]{
        new Product("Dr.Pepper", 5, 1.00),
        new Product("Coca Cola", 6, 1.00),
        new Product("Fanta", 7, 1.00),
        new Product("Sprite", 8, 1.00),
        new Product("Redbull", 9, 1.00),
        new Product("Orange Juice", 10, 1.00)
    }; 

if(source.equals(nextButton)){

          getNameField.setText(myProduct[++pointer].getName()); 
          getStockLevelField.setText(String.valueOf(myProduct[++pointer].getStockLevel()));
          getPriceField.setText(String.valueOf(myProduct[++pointer].getPrice()));

            }
        }
```

Link examples:

[Object 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFUlG.png)

[Object 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBlB3.png)

You can see that the button works and iterates only by 1. I want it so that I can iterate through all of the objects one by one.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What is difficulties you have? You do not know how to handle pressing a button?

Comment: Can you put a link to an example, please?

Comment: @talex I have added an example.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No need to comment if you're not going to help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "That for loop makes absolutely no sense. Get rid of it." this comment doesn't make it look like you're going to help me. You may have noticed that I'm a novice programmer. I am here for help. Not cheeky answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm open to help but your comment doesn't benefit me at all. I'm unclear to why you're making it look like I'm rejecting your help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels To clarify you came to my post and told me to "That for loop makes absolutely no sense. Get rid of it." and you're telling me I'm rejecting your help. And now you have deleted that comment because you know it makes 0 of sense. It's like saying I'll help you but I won't. It's just demotivating rather than helping.

Comment: This sort of problem has been asked and answered many times on this site and other sites previously. Please see this [link to similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+next+previous+buttons). No, you won't be able to borrow exact code from these similar questions, but you can borrow the ideas that the answers contain and use these to create your own code. Luck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this comment is more beneficial than your previous one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define new Integer like this:

```
int pointer = 0;
```

This Integer Stores current viewed index of array.so in button click do this:

A)For next: `myProduct[++pointer].getName();`

B)For Previous: `myProduct[--pointer].getName();`

Note:you must check pointer on each click that is it less than 0 for previous and greater than lenght of myProduct.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use a variable to simulate the operation of the pointer, by controlling the increase or decrease of the integer to achieve the positioning of the contents of the array, as the last one to answer.

Define a `int index`, choose the object by `myProduct[index]`.

Hope this can help you!